# Transferring a mobile app from one parse account tonanother

Tags: parse-platform

I would like to know if it's currently possible to transfer an app created on one parse account to another users parse account.

We have had an external developer build part of our apps backend on parse but he has not used our businesses parse account.

Please could you let me know if it possible to change it / port it over?

Many Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. It is found on the Settings-->Collaborators page for the app you want to transfer.

[image: Screen shot]